# How to grep for two patterns in multiple files

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep

I have multiple files in multiple directories, and I need a grep command which can return the output only when both the patterns are present in the file. The patterns are like `AccessToken` and `Registrationrequest`. The patterns are not in the same line. `AccessToken` can be in one line and `Registrationrequest` can be in another line. Also search the same recursively across all files in all directories.

Tried

```
grep -r "string1” /directory/file |  grep "string 2” 
grep -rl 'string 1' | xargs grep 'string2' -l /directory/ file
grep -e string1 -e string2
```

Nothing works

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just in case the files are very large and making two passes on them is expensive and you want just the filenames, using `find`+`awk`:

```
find . -type f -exec awk 'FNR == 1 {a=0; r=0} /AccessToken/{a=1} /Registrationrequest/{r=1} a && r {print FILENAME; nextfile}' {} +
```

- we set two flag variables `a` and `r` for when the corresponding patterns were found, cleared at the start of each file (`FNR == 1`)
- when both variables are true, we print the filename and move on to the next file.

Comment: @muru can help with syntax of saving the filename to a file instead of printing it

Comment: @user1573232 just put a `> output-file` at the end of the command

Answer (score 5):

The following command can print out when the file matches the search criteria:

```
grep -Zril 'String1' | xargs -0 grep -il 'String2'
```

Here is an example:

```
~/tmp$ ls
Dir1  Dir2  File1  File2

cat File1
AccessToken is not here
Registrationrequest it is here

cat File2
iAccess
ByteMe Registrationrequest
```

I copied both `File1` and `File2` into the `Dir1` and `Dir2` for testing:

```
~/tmp$ grep -Zril 'AccessToken' | xargs -0 grep -il 'Registrationrequest'
File1
Dir2/File1
Dir1/File1
```

Then if you want to see what is in the files add the following to the end of the search:

```
xargs grep -E "AccessToken|Registrationrequest"
```

Example:

```
~/tmp$ grep -Zril 'AccessToken' | xargs -0 grep -il 'Registrationrequest' | xargs grep -E "AccessToken|Registrationrequest"
File1:AccessToken is not here
File1:Registrationrequest it is here
Dir2/File1:AccessToken is not here
Dir2/File1:Registrationrequest it is here
Dir1/File1:AccessToken is not here
Dir1/File1:Registrationrequest it is here
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -Erzl 'STR1.*STR2|STR2.*STR1'
```

where option `-z` ends up slurping the files as a single line.

More precisely:

```
grep -Erzl 'AccessToken.*Registrationrequest|Registrationrequest.*AccessToken'
```

Answer (score 1):

#### `while` loop

This may not be as clever or resource-effective as other solutions, but it works:

```bsh
while read -rd '' filename; do
    if grep -q "AccessToken" "$filename" && 
        grep -q "Registrationrequest" "$filename"
    then
        echo "$filename"
    fi
done < <(find . -type f -print0)
```